# Old .js file STILL being served, even though cache and DNS are flushed

Tags: javascript, azure, caching, dns

I have updated a javascript file and deployed it to my website (using azure) as usual.

I then cleared my cache and tested the webpage BUT - it still serves the old javascript file.
I have checked through FTP and see that the file IS updated, I have accessed the file from other computer and they receive the updated version.

However, even if I use Fiddler from my main computer I still receive the old file.

I have flushed my DNS too, but I still get the old file.

The strange thing is, when I update any other JS file it is retrieving the updated one without any issues - it is ONLY this specific JS file.

What could be causing this? My cache is cleared, my DNS is flushed - why am I still receiving an old version of my file?

By the way, the host is Microsoft Azure, using a standard Web App.

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing this from work/somewhere public (i.e. not home), then their servers could be caching the file too in order to save bandwidth. You have two options:

(A) Ask your server admin to change the server settings so it wont cache from your domain.

(B) Wait some time.

I have exactly the same problem when developing from my place of work. I usually only deploy from localhost when I am totally satisfied it is going to work!

Comment: I see. I will try to switch to my phone network and see if it changes anything.

Comment: I tried to access the file through my phone network but I still receive the old file. Thus is can't be network related but gotta be something with my specific computer.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me sometimes too, interesting is that you will see the updated file on azure console but the old stuff is served.

One solution is to restart the Website from Azure Portal and wait a few minutes.